# Arduino SPI Communication with H3LIS100DL accelerometer

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, accelerometer

I'm having trouble getting information off the accelerometer I'm trying to use. What code should I use to read the X,Y, and Z axis?  I've read the data sheet but I don't have any experience with SPI communication.

[Spec sheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/6e/c2/95/d9/3a/3f/4f/cb/DM00162193.pdf/files/DM00162193.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00162193.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The basic [SPI](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI) operations looks like this. First read single register:

```
uint8_t readRegister(int index)
{
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPI_SETTING);
  SPI.transfer(READ | index);
  uint8_t res = SPI.transfer(0);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
  return (res);
}
```

And second write single register:

```
void writeRegister(int index, uint8_t data)
{
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPI_SETTING);
  SPI.transfer(WRITE | index);
  SPI.transfer(data);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}
```

Some more details:

```
const uint8_t WRITE = 0x00;
const uint8_t READ = 0x80;
```

It is also possible to read/write a sequence of registers by providing the register index with the MS set. This will auto-increment the register index.

SPI_SETTING is left as an exercise (to be updated).

Cheers!